# Finding $E(X^2)$ for the given pdf

Tags: probability

Let  $X$  be distributed according to the pdf  $$ke^{−x^2−7x}.$$  Find  $E(X^2)$ .

Can some please help me on this topic ?

I know I have to convert it to normal distribution but I'm confused here total kindly someone help me. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKsnj.png) is a picture of the question.

Comment: Complete the square; pattern match.

Comment: i have try but it give me some random equation .

Comment: $Ke^{-x(x+7)}$ is that equation that coming after completing the square i don not uderstand how it help me to determinr the value of mean and stadard deviation.

Comment: i know i have to use this formula to find the answer  E[X^2] = Var(X) + (E[X])^2).

Comment: What constant to you have to add to $x^2+7x$ to make it a perfect square? That is, for what $A$ can you write $x^2+7x+A=(cx+d)^2$ for some $c$ and $d$?  Hint: it should be easy to predict what $c$ must be.

Comment: A should be 12.25

Comment: Very good!  And what are $c$ and $d$?  And how can you combine what you get with what you know about the normal distribution  and with your correct observation about the variance and the second moment?

Comment: why we need c and d @kimchi lover

Answer (score 3):

Since you have the pdf, we must have
$\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^\infty k e^{-x^2-7x} dx = 1$

Let us compare it with the pdf of the Normal Distribution.

$e^{-x^2-7x} = \left(e^{\frac{49}{4}}\right)e^{- \left(x - (-\frac{7}{2})\right)^2}$

Specifically, compare $e^{- \left(x - (-\frac{7}{2})\right)^2}$ and $e^{-\frac{(x -\mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}}$

Hence we can choose $\mu = -\frac{7}{2}$ and $\sigma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

$E(X^2) = \mu^2 + \sigma^2 = \frac{51}{4} = 12.75$

[Also note that  $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-\frac{(x -\mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}}dx = 1 = \displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^\infty k e^{-x^2-7x} dx$

Comparing, $k = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} e^{-\frac{49}{4}}$]

Comment: It is $\mu=\large{\color{red}-\frac72}$. You can  read it off directly from what you´ve written.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have fixed the typo.